# Sliding Expiration with Identity Server 4 and ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, identityserver4

The setup is pretty simple: ASP.NET Core MVC (3.1) Client which is protected with Identity Server 4 with Authorization Code Flow.

Task is to make sliding expiration: session should become invalid after 1 min of inactivity.

Settings which I applied:

in the Client:

```
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
  options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
  options.SlidingExpiration = true;
})
```

in the Identity Server:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
{
  options.Authentication.CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
  options.Authentication.CookieSlidingExpiration = true;
})
```

What I have at the moment: sliding expiration works for client cookie (so when 30sec+ passes, client cookie is getting renewed on subsequent request). Same works for IDSRV (when I go to the login page, login, then wait 30+ seconds and refresh the page, cookie passes in request and response, meaning it's updated). But it doesn't work in conjunction. IDSRV cookie is never getting updated with request made on the client.

I understand it like that: since they have the same expiration (1min), the request to IDSRV /authorize is never made, until client's cookie is valid. So in this case I will always be in the same situation - I can be logged in to the client, because I have a client's cookie and in 1 minute I will be logged out of IDSRV, because no requests are made to it - there is no way to refresh it's cookie.

Ok, in that case I can make IDSRV's cookie lifetime twice bigger (2 min), though it goes against my requirements. But even in this case IDSRV's cookie is not slided - so I'm logged out of IDSRV after 2 minutes if I don't touch it directly. What I mean: let's say I didn't touch Client for 1min+, it makes my client's cookie invalid and it causes a request to IDSRV. Cookie is present in response, but it's not sliding.

So my assumption is that I'm doing something wrong. What will be the correct way to implement sliding session?

Answer (score 2):

To make it work you also need to ***turn off*** the `Token Lifetime` so you are not overriding SlidingExpirationm which is on your Cookie middleware only.

### just add `UseTokenLifetime = false;`

[MSDN ref](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/147)

---

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions    
{
    ...
    UseTokenLifetime = false, 
    ...    
});
```